# (Push notifications) Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js)

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currenly working on firebase cloud functions with messaging (fcm) and I want to call the functions that I've created:

**functions -> src-> index.ts**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

export const sendOnFirestoreCreate =  functions.firestore
.document('ticket/{ticketId}')
.onCreate(async snapshot => {
    const ticket = snapshot.data();
    const notification: admin.messaging.Notification = {
        title: 'Nuevo ticket de falla registrado',
        body: ticket.headline

    };

    const payload: admin.messaging.Message = {
        notification,
        webpush:{
            notification: {
                vibrate: [200,100,200],
                icon: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/6360/6360061.png'
            }
        },
        topic: 'ticket'
    };
    return admin.messaging().send(payload);
});
```

**src->app->services->fcm.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/compat/messaging';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { tap } from 'rxjs';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FcmService {
  token;
  constructor(
    private afMessaging: AngularFireMessaging,
    private fun: AngularFireFunctions,
    private toastController: ToastController
  ) { }

  async makeToast(message){
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message,
      duration: 6000,
      position: 'top',
      showCloseButton: true,
      closeButtonText: 'x'
    });

    toast.present();
  }


  getPermission(){
    return this.afMessaging.requestToken.pipe(
      tap(token => (this.token = token))
    );
  }

  showMessages(){
    return this.afMessaging.messages.pipe(
      tap(msg => {
        const body: any = (msg as any).notification.body;
        this.makeToast(body);
      })
    );
  }
  send(ticket){
    this.fun.httpsCallable('sendOnFirestoreCreate')({ticket, token: this.token})
    .pipe(tap(_=> this.makeToast(`New ticket ${ticket}`))).subscribe();
  }
}
```

**src->app->pages->tickets.page.ts**

```
import { InteractionUserService } from './../../services/interaction-user.service';
import { Ticket } from './../../interfaces/interfaces';
import { FirestoreService } from './../../services/firestore.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FcmService } from './../../services/fcm.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tickets',
  templateUrl: './tickets.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tickets.page.scss'],
})
export class TicketsPage implements OnInit {
  data: Ticket = {
    fecha: '',
    hora:'',
    area: '',
    folio: null,
  };

 
  constructor(
    private firestore: FirestoreService,
    private interaction: InteractionUserService,
    private fcm: FcmService
  ) {

  }


//SOME CODE
// **********

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  createTicket() {
      this.interaction.presentLoading('Loading...');
      const path = 'ticket';
      const id = this.firestore.getId();
      this.data.id = id;

      //here I call the push notification functions

      this.fcm.getPermission();
      this.fcm.send(path);
   
      this.firestore.createDoc(this.data, path, id ).then((res) => {
        console.log('Ticket saved successfully ->', res);
        this.interaction.closeLoading();
        this.interaction.toastMessageSuccess('¡Ticket saved!');
        
      }).catch(err => {

        console.log('Error->', err);
        this.interaction.closeLoading();
        this.interaction.toastMessageFail('Oops, reaload and try again please.');

      });
  }
}
```

**Now I'm getting this error:**
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
[ng] Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.
[ng]
[ng] Error: Failed to initialize Angular compilation - The target entry-point "ionic-angular" has missing dependencies:
[ng]  - rxjs/Subject
[ng]  - rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil

Any help is VERY appreciated, I'm really stuck, thanks in advance!!

Some other info...

This is my package.json, I don't know if the problem could be here...

```
{
  "name": "ticketsApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~14.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "~14.2.7",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "~14.2.7",
    "@capacitor/app": "4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "4.3.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "4.0.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.3.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.1.0",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.0.1",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "firebase": "^9.12.1",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic": "^5.4.16",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.10",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.7",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~14.2.6",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~14.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~14.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~14.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~14.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~14.2.7",
    "@capacitor/cli": "4.3.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.40.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.40.1",
    "eslint": "^8.25.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "39.3.14",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: Please include the full package.json file contents. Initially, it looks like you are missing rxjs dependency given the error message.

Comment: Hello, I updated that part, I'm not sure if just   "rxjs": "~7.5.7", could be enough... thanks in advance :)

Comment: I tried npm i rxjs@latest but still the same error :-(

Comment: It appears the project is using angular v14 with ionic 5 and ionic-angular v3.9? This doesn't appear to be a supported combination on ionic website https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/support#ionic-angular